# Compilation failure with -I/usr/include/linux

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors

I am trying to find why I am getting the following errors when I am compiling a simple program (printing hello world) while providing the include path /usr/include/linux. How does inclusion of this path affect the search path. I tried compiling in verbose mode but did not get much clue. If I remove the include path the compilation is successful as usual. I want to understand what effect does this include path have on the compilation process.

```
gcc -o check -I/usr/include/linux check.c In file included from
/usr/include/stdio.h:43,
                 from check.c:1: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/struct_FILE.h:95:3: error:
unknown type name 'size_t'    95 |   size_t __pad5;
      |   ^~~~~~ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/struct_FILE.h:98:67: error:
'size_t' undeclared here (not in a function)    98 |   char
_unused2[15 * sizeof (int) - 4 * sizeof (void *) - sizeof (size_t)];
      |                                                                   ^~~~~~ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/struct_FILE.h:1:1:
note: 'size_t' is defined in header '<stddef.h>'; did you forget to
'#include <stddef.h>'?   +++ |+#include <stddef.h>
    1 | /* Copyright (C) 1991-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc. /usr/include/stdio.h:292:35: error: expected declaration specifiers or
'...' before 'size_t'   292 | extern FILE *fmemopen (void *__s, size_t
__len, const char *__modes)
      |                                   ^~~~~~ /usr/include/stdio.h:298:47: error: expected declaration specifiers or
'...' before 'size_t'   298 | extern FILE *open_memstream (char
**__bufloc, size_t *__sizeloc) __THROW __wur;
      |                                               ^~~~~~ /usr/include/stdio.h:309:34: error: expected declaration specifiers or
'...' before 'size_t'   309 |                     int __modes, size_t
__n) __THROW;
      |                                  ^~~~~~ /usr/include/stdio.h:315:24: error: expected declaration specifiers or
'...' before 'size_t'   315 |                        size_t __size)
__THROW;
      |                        ^~~~~~ /usr/include/stdio.h:354:44: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'size_t'   354
| extern int snprintf (char *__restrict __s, size_t __maxlen,
```

Comment: Yes, you have compilation errors ... Please _edit_ your question and post the entire/full source file (i.e. `check.c` file) that causes these errors in a separate code block.

Comment: `#include <stddef.h>`

Comment: When you do: `-I/usr/include/linux`, when your source file does: `#include <stddef.h>` or any other `#include` that includes it (e.g. `#include <stdio.h>`), the compiler is using `/usr/include/linux/stddef.h` [which is used by _kernel_ sources--_not_ what you want] instead of `/usr/include/stddef.h` [which is for userspace apps and is what you _do_ want].

Comment: Thanks Craig. I can resolve it by using -idirafter to change the searchpath. -I is simply putting it in the top of the searchpath list.