# What does __kernel_size_t data type in C header file mean?

Tags: c, c-libraries, c-header

I was looking thought the `string.h` header file when I found a data type called `__kernel_size_t`.

I couldn't find anything of interest about it's meaning so I'm asking here.

I'm running linux and it's location is `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-91/include/linux/string.h`  if it helps

Comment: Depending on the platform it is probably just `typedef`ed to an `unsigned long` or something similar. Kernel internal stuff. You don't need to know about it unless you are programming kernel modules or the kernel itself. It is not used in user space, and as such not in C libraries or headers intended for user space.

Comment: You're looking at the _kernel_ source and not the application/userspace `/usr/include/string.h` See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72666261/compilation-failure-with-i-usr-include-linux

Comment: alright, I'll keep both of your answers in mind